# Would loading images from assets folder instead of res folder reduce preloaded images on Android?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

[image]

We know that nothing can be done for `android.content.res.Resources`as it is caused by `Zygote` to preload some resources that we cannot directly manipulate.

I am not exactly sure about how it preloads and where it preloads from. For example, shall I move my image files from `res/drawable-hdpi` to assets folder? (Note that I only have 1 copy of the images in `res` folder. So the same `drawable` is used for (hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shall I move my image files from res/drawable-hdpi to assets folder?

No, I don't think copying image resources to asset directory of your project will make any thing much change.

It's recommend to have these resources in `res` folder and access those image, `asset` folder is for different purpose like have any static html page, keep custom font of your application.

Lastly, You should keep images resources in res directory and try to keep their size as minimum as possible.

Comment: Would `raw` folder make a difference?

Comment: So those preloaded Images are completely irrelevant to user-added images?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean of user added images.

Comment: My bad. Developer added images (: non-system images. Images those we add to the project for any purpose.